# How to quote something already quoted

Tags: quotations

I read an article where the author mentions a sentence from a third person. For instance, Nancy K. has an article where she writes:

> "something" (David F)

I want to reproduce the sentence and also give credit to the person that let me discover it. How to do that? is this correct? :

> "something" (David F., through Nancy K.)

Comment: People in general do not give credit to the person who quoted the person saying the quote. I've never seen this used, so I don't know how you would do it. You can put quotes inside quotes by using alternate single and double quotes: "It is written that The King said 'Let all of these "merry-makers" and "celebrators" be feasted and accomodated!' in this paper"

Comment: What are you writing?  A journal article?  An academic paper?  A business white paper?  A press release?  A gossip column?  A newsletter?  A blog post?  A diary entry?

Comment: If you are writing a journal article or an academic paper, then this question should be migrated to [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you looked at the document by David F. (not just the document by Nancy K.)?

Comment: If you are writing a gossip column, I recommend looking at how [Herb Caen](http://www.sfgate.com/herbcaen/) handled this issue.  (Sadly, the SFGate archive reformats Caen's famous "three dots" as "horizontal rules".)  If you are writing a blog post, I recommend looking at how [Instapundit](https://pjmedia.com/instapundit/) handles this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea works. But *per* is the word to use, not *through*:

> "Four score and seven years ago" (Abraham Lincoln, per [CNN.com](http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/19/us/gettysburg-address-famous-quotes/index.html))

This would mean that CNN.com says that Abraham Lincoln said this, as can be seen in the link. (You don't have to include a link, but if you are writing a blog post, it's the best way to handle attribution.)

*Per* in this case means according to.